# I would like to avoid using `.flat()` and use `.reduce` instead in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have

- an **array** of strings `const rooms = ['roomA', 'roomB', 'roomC']`.
- an **object** that has

```
const roomOccupants = { 
  'roomA': [{name: 'player1'}, {name: 'player555'}], 
  'roomB': [{name: 'player2'}, {name: 'player3'}] 
}
```

I have added the players from `roomA` & `roomB` to a new room say `roomABC` using the map function below however `roomABC` needs to be flattened using `.flat()` array method bc the returned value structure is `[{}, {}], [{}, {}]`.
I was wondering if there is a way that I could avoid using `.flat()` maybe using `.reduce()` could achieve that but I was not able to figure it out.

```
const roomABC = rooms.map((roomName) => {
  return roomOccupants[roomName];
});
```

I need the output to be as follows. No need for unique items/order of the items in the array. Thanks in advance.

```
const roomABC = [{name: 'player1'}, {name: 'player2'}, {name: 'player3'}, {name: 'player555'}]
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `flat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const rooms = ['roomA', 'roomB', 'roomC'];

const roomOccupants = { 
  'roomA': [{name: 'player1'}, {name: 'player555'}], 
  'roomB': [{name: 'player2'}, {name: 'player3'}] 
};

const roomABC = rooms.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  if(roomOccupants[curr]){
    acc = acc.concat(roomOccupants[curr]);
  }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(roomABC);

/* Prints :
[
  {
    "name": "player1"
  },
  {
    "name": "player555"
  },
  {
    "name": "player2"
  },
  {
    "name": "player3"
  }
]
*/
```

Here ***acc*** is the accumulated result and ***curr*** is the current value.

The reducer function gets called for every element of the ***rooms*** array. So in the above code snippet, ***curr*** will take values *"room1", "room2", and "room3"*.

We start with an empty list, ***[]*** as the initial value of ***acc***.

The function checks if ***roomOccupants[curr]*** exists and if it does, concatenates it's value with the previous value of ***acc***.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well written and explained! +1 In ES6 syntax you can even write it as a one-liner: `const roomABC = rooms.reduce((a,c) => [...a,...roomOccupants[c]??[]],[])`.

Comment: is there a quick way to incorporate only unique players in the output array? @CarstenMassmann

Answer (score 0):

The following would be the code for non-repeating players:

```js
const rooms = ['roomA', 'roomB', 'roomC'];

const roomOccupants = { 
  'roomA': [{name: 'player1'}, {name: 'player555'}], 
  'roomB': [{name: 'player1'}, {name: 'player3'}],
  'roomD': [{name: 'harry'}]
};

const roomABC = Object.values(rooms.reduce((a,r,os) =>{
 if (os=roomOccupants[r])
  os.forEach(o=>a[o.name]=o);
 return a;
},{}))

console.log(roomABC);
```